# file_get_contents with $context is super slow

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

So I'm adding a search like feature to my site where users can get text,image,and video results.

The function is quite simple

```
<?php
// $query is passed from the search form input
function getVideo($query) {
$opts = array('https'=>array('header'=> 'Connection: close'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$pattern = "/<title ?.*>(.*)<\/title>/";
preg_match($pattern, file_get_contents($query,false,$context), $matches);
return $matches[1];
}
```

Here is an example url to scrape
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=2013%20BMW%20X3%20xDrive28i&start-index=11&max-results=1

All I need to do is get the title of the video and it takes 6 seconds.
Any suggestions? I've read some articles about using curl but for many it doesn't reduce the server wait time.

Comment: Was fairly fast on mine using that exact script with URL provided. 200MS execution time.

Comment: Use `cURL` :) And compare speed.

Comment: @Kris it seems to only slow things down when I place it inside a while loop (while loop it set to break after looping 15 times). Outside the loop it loads around that same time it does for you.
Outside the loop it takes 7+ seconds

Comment: How many are you trying to do? Because if you are trying to do 30, that would equal 6 seconds @ 200 ms each.

Comment: @Kris I was doing 15 =/ (which should technically be 3 seconds but..) I'll try cURL since it supposedly does all at the same time? Not sure.